# Cannot extract jester dataset in windows 10

Tags: gzip, tar, cat, 7zip, jester

I know that this topic already appears in other posts but I'm not able to solve it and your help would be very much appreciated.

I'm trying to extract the Jester V1 Hand Gesture Recognition dataset but, when you download it, it comes in a very strange format. I've tried the command `cat 20bn-jester-v1-?? | tar zx` in the Windows Powershell which made my computer run something (don't know what) for several hours (I know that it was running because my computer was slow) but nothing changed in the file. And in the command line (this second option gave me an error). I've also tried to extract them with 7zip and was able to extract the first file but I couldn't accomplish it with the rest.
Please help, I'm using Windows 10 and have already installed 7zip and here's a screenshot of the files.
Thank you so much!

[image: screenshot of the files]

Comment: Their instructions are: ```After downloading all parts, extract using:

cat 20bn-jester-v1-?? | tar zx```

Comment: One solution (not ideal) is to download the partial dataset on kaggle: here's the link: [click here](https://www.kaggle.com/toxicmender/20bn-jester/version/3)

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://github.com/udacity/CVND---Gesture-Recognition) says to `cat 20bn-jester-v1-?? | tar zx` to extract the videos. However it also says that those 23 pieces are about 1 GB each. Your screen shot shows them as less than 1 *MB* each. Perhaps something went wrong further upstream.

Comment: I think that the images are the ones without extension. They are about 900 000 KB which is 0.9GB. I don't think that that's the problem....

Comment: Then why does it say 976.563 KB? That looks like 1 MB to me. Not 1 GB.

Comment: The videos are _not_ the ones without extensions. You will note that they are all _exactly_ the same size. They are clearly a split of a larger file, which is what it says in the documentation I linked. Those pieces need to be concatenated to be extracted, which is what `cat` does. If those really are 1 GB pieces, then you need to type the command in my answer.

Comment: I'm running again the command, just in case, but the first time what it did was to finish in the windows powershell and no files/folders appeared. (it takes like 5 hours) I edited the post and shared the image where it says the memory used by each file (and btw the last file is of a different size which makes sense cause there are no more images left). Sorry because my computer is in spanish. Thanks for your help again :)

Comment: Do you have documentation for the tar command in your shell? It may not have exactly the same options. I would try `tar tvz` first, to _list_ the files that would be written, which will also show you where it will be writing them.

Comment: My guess is that it's working just fine, but you don't know where the files have been written.

Comment: It has been running for 10 hours now and still hasn't finished... As soon as it finishes,  I will try the ```tar tvz ```. I just have to change the ```tar zx``` for ```tar tvz``` right?

Comment: Yes. It shouldn't take ten hours. How old is your machine? It should take less than an hour.

Comment: It's like 2 years old. It has a ryzen 1700, a gtx 1060 and a ssd... I couldn't solve the problem but I found that the dataset is partially on kaggle so I will work with it for now. I also contacted the company behind this dataset for support. Thank you so much for your help, will post a solution if I find one. Thanks again! ;)

Comment: My four-year old machine would take less than hour.

Comment: There must be something wrong with my machine or with the data... Thank you so much again for your interest

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I found to this problem is to install the Linux terminal on windows with ubuntu.